# Copy items from a List to a array with fixed size

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a `List<int>` which returns n values.

I have to store those values into a array with fixed length of `10`

- if there are more than 10 items, the will be cut off
- if there are less than 10 items, the free spots should be filled with the digit `0`

my approach

```
int[] result = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
List<int> items = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList();
items.CopyTo(result); // 1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0
```

But this fails at items `> 10`
Is there a way to do this instantly or at least with less than 3 lines of code?

Comment: you can remove the linebreaks...

Comment: No this code doesn't work if the OP has more than 10 items in that list.

Comment: even tho my first comment seems to be funny what I actually tried to say:
Let the compiler reduce lines for you. Your job is it to write readable code and your code is readable

Comment: @DenisSchaf the funny thing is that you didn't notice my mistake in 3 lines of code and become salty

Comment: `items.CopyTo(0, result, 0, Math.Min(items.Count, result.Length))`. Overloads FTW.

Comment: i don't understand how your a mistake makes me salty..

Comment: @Dr.Snail I retracted my closing vote. Note that your 3 lines of code, only 2 are the "copying list items to an array" the other one is just initializing the list, which you'll probably receive as a parameter, if this was a method

Comment: @JeroenMostert that for example is one line but a lot harder to read

Comment: @DenisSchaf and removing line breaks makes it better to read? (see your first comment)

Comment: okay I'm out of this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Enumerable.Take()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.7.2) method combined with the [`Array.Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length?view=netframework-4.7.2) property to always choose—at most—as many elements can fit into the array:

```
var result = new int[10];
var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 11);
items.Take(result.Length).ToList().CopyTo(result);
```

When there are less than `result.Length` items (10 in this example), the empty slots will be populated with `default(int)`, i.e. `0`.

Comment: Why not just `ToArray()`?

Comment: @Adrian OP requested for the items of the enumerable to be copied to an existing array of fixed size. Or did you mean using `.ToArray()` in place of `.ToList()`?

Comment: yeah. i dont' think he meant an existing array, since in any case it would have been overwritten anyway. so `ToArray()` instead of `ToList().CopyTo(result)` would be sufficient, i'd say.

Comment: @Adrian hmm, I believe OP wanted to copy the items of the enumerable to an existing array of fixed size, and `.CopyTo()` would fail if the enumerable contained more items than the size of the array (`ArgumentException` would be thrown). I `.ToList()`ed so I could access `.CopyTo()`, I could indeed have used `.ToArray()` instead, by modifying the last line to `items.Take(result.Length).ToArray().CopyTo(result, 0);`

Answer (score 2):

You can cut of your array by using [`Enumerable.Take(int count)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
int inputCount = 10;

int[] result = new int[inputCount];
Enumerable.Range(1, inputCount / 2).Take(inputCount).ToList().CopyTo(result);
// 1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0

// 5 items as input
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

Enumerable.Range(1, inputCount * 2).Take(inputCount).ToList().CopyTo(result);
// 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

// 20 items as input
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

You perhaps want to read somthing about [`Enumerable.Skip(int count)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.7.2), too. This skips records..

```
Enumerable.Range(1, inputCount * 2).Skip(10).Take(inputCount).ToList().CopyTo(result);
// 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19

// 20 items as input. skipped 10
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> items = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList();
int[] result = items.Take(10).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, Math.Max( 10 - items.Count,0))).ToArray();
```

Comment: Please, elaborate on your answer. Code-only answers are considered low-quality.